# Name of Hive table is now a reserved keyword

Tags: hadoop, hive

One of my hive tables has a column named "location" which is now a reserved keyword. I want to create a copy of the table in development, is there any way to get around the name during the create table statement? If I do something like

```
CREATE TABLE users (id int, location string);
```

I see:

```
FAILED: Parse Error: line 1:0 mismatched input ''location'' expecting Identifier near ',' in column specification
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
CREATE TABLE users (`id` int, `location` string);
```

Comment: Could you also provide an example of query please?